# How to load images using SDWebImage library

Tags: ios, sdwebimage

Hi I am using `SDWebImage` for loading images ok that's fine

Here I am getting images from services and  I want to resize those images and I want to load them using `SDWebImage`

for this I wrote the code below

```
Obj.imageYH---> this is imageURL

  NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:Obj.imageYH]];

    UIImage *actualImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(150, 150));
    [actualImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,150, 150)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    NSData *smallData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

    NSString *Finalstring = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:smallData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] ;


    [Mainimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: Finalstring] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"collectionViewIcon.png"]];
```

but in the code above, I am getting null value in `Finalstring`. How can I resize it and how can I load images using `SDWebImage`?

Comment: Wait. that's weird. `sd_setImageWithURL:` requires a URL of the image (e.g. http://example.com/image.jpg), instead of string representation of the image data. You should use `Obj.imageYH`. `SDWebImage` is a library to load image from Internet asynchronously. You misuse it to load a resized image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below line of codes instead of your code :

```
UIImage *actualImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(150, 150));
[actualImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,150, 150)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
NSData *smallData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);

[smallData writeToFile:Finalstring atomically:YES];// Finalstring is file path of resize image 

[Mainimage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: Finalstring] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"collectionViewIcon.png"]];
```

Comment: That's not related to the question at all.

Comment: @Raptor thanks for the attention.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: /how can we find Finalstring is file path of resize image ?

Comment: It is path where you want to store resize image. like in document directory. Something like below line of code
`NSString *smalFilename = @"smallimage.png"; 

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *finalString = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:smalFilename];`

Comment: ho w can we find that path?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108381/discussion-between-payal-maniyar-and-krish).

Comment: @PayalManiyar this does not use the advantage of SDWebImage to download image asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: Installation of SDWebImage**

To start with, make sure you're using the latest version of `SDWebImage`, and installed via CocoaPods (not recommend to link up the library manually).

Your Podfile should contain this line:

```
pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.7'
```

After that, close the Xcode project and run `pod install` in your project directory. Use the Xcode **workspace** after installation.

---

**Step 2: Using the codes**

First of all, you have the import the library

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

At this moment, try to Clean & Build the Workspace. If everything goes well, the project should be built without error.

Then, in your function:

```
SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
[manager downloadImageWithURL:Obj.imageYH
                  options:0
                 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
                     // progression tracking code, optional. 
                     // You can set the progress block to nil
                 }
                 completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
                     if (image) {
                         // Resize your image here, then set it to UIImageView
                         Mainimage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) scale:0.5f]; 
                         // resize to 0.5x, function available since iOS 6
                     }
                 }];
```

done.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
 [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self options:0 success:^(UIImage
 *image)  {
     cell.profilePicture.image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width,
 cell.profilePicture.frame.size.height) image:image]; } failure:nil];
```

Don't forget to include

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <SDWebImageManagerDelegate>
```

Comment: #import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h> error showing in this line

Comment: [manager downloadWithURL:url delegate:self options:0 success:^(UIImage
 *image)  {
     cell.profilePicture.image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(cell.profilePicture.frame.size.width,
 cell.profilePicture.frame.size.height) image:image]; } failure:nil];

Comment: dude this is my code use your own logic and your own code then only it will work.

Comment: [manager downloadWithURL:string delegate:self options:0 success:^(UIImage
                                                                   *image)  {
        cell.profilePicture.image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:CGSizeMake(150,
                                                                                      150) image:image]; } failure:nil];

Comment: Wait. @amitsoni you're using old version of SDWebImage. Update your codes with Cocoapods. Syntax changed for months already.

Comment: @Raptor can u give me answer please